# watchman cli options for watching multiple folders with exclusion and inclusion list, trigger a script and see the stdout/stderr of the script

Tags: facebook, command-line-interface, watchman

Is there any watchman guru here? I'd like to know the command line options to watch .go files but not dist/ in server, watch *.js, *.jsx, but not dist/ and node_modules/ in webapp, and trigger build_deploy.sh script.  And also, is there a way to tail the stdout/stderr when the build_deploy.sh is executing?

Answer (score -1):

Checkout watchman triggers: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/cmd/trigger.html

You should be able to set up a trigger that runs build_deploy.sh when only files matching your criteria change. It also has options to control where stdout and stderr go, so you could write them to your own log file somewhere.

Comment: I was hoping someone can give me the exact command line options, so I don't have to spend time trying the options.  I wanted to start from what's already working.